# convert the colors of the pixels in the picture to a value between 0 and 1

Tags: graph, colors, visualization, heatmap

here is the gist of my problem:
I have a structural map showing the content of oil saturation. I would like to know the algorithm for converting pixel color to oil saturation (value from 0 to 1 or from 0 to 100%)

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwmdv.png)

I tried to convert the color format to a brightness value (0.299R+0.587G+0.144B), but that didn't help, because the values ​​were not logical.[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjmeL.png)

Comment: Please clarify your problem.  The legend in the bottom left seems to be a guide to interpretation of the colors.  Why not use that? Grab the pixel color, look it up in a table constructed from the legend to get the value.

Comment: The problem is that I need to process a lot of these pictures that have an oil saturation value. but they are not on the Internet, so I want to solve the "inverse" problem. take an array of oil saturation values ​​from the constructed map. To do this, I need to convert an array of RGB values ​​into an array of the desired parameter

Comment: I still do not understand what is stopping you.  You have the RGB values.  You have the legend that allows you to look up a value from the RGB values.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: There are three steps.  . grab the RGB values from a pixel, 2. Look up the grabbed values in a table.  3. Output the value you looked up in the table.  What step are you stuck on?

Comment: probably on step 2)
The legend shown in the picture goes with it. it looks like the task has been reduced to setting this legend on your own. also, not all maps have this legend

Comment: I think to get some kind of distribution algorithm from this data and use it further for data that does not have a legend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are just 18 different colors.  Construct a table with 18 rows and 4 columns ( red, green, blue, value )  The value should be evenly spaced between 0 and 1 in the order shown by the legend.

Grab the RGB value for each pixel and look it up the value in the table.

If there is no legend then things become arbitrary unless you can use information about the significance of the colors from another source.  I understand that some of your diagrams do have legends - would it be reasonable to use the legend from another image - that is assume the same legend is implied for all the images?

Comment: hi, your first answer really helped me. I took 18 values ​​from the legend, converted RGB to another format (to get one value, not three. Further, through the trend line, I got a formula for translation, the values ​​seem to converge